# Is there some 3rd party mode for codemirror to edit apache and squid config files

Tags: apache, squid, codemirror, ace-editor

In my current project, I need to edit apache and squid config file in web browser. After some searching with Google, I decided to use CodeMirror. But CodeMirror does not come with support for apache and squid config file syntax.  Although CodeMirror can be extended to support other formats, but I'am new to CodeMirror, I think it may need a lot of time to write a product level mode plugin.Is there any 3rd party mode for apache and squid that can work with CodeMirror?

And what about Ace, if Ace can support apache and squid, it acceptable for me to switch to it.

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

Both codemirror and ace do not support this now (see http://codemirror.net/mode/index.html and http://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html), but Ace can import syntax highlighters from textmate/sublime text/gedit, so if you have a syntax highlighter for one of these editors submit mode request to https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/new, and it will be added quickly.